# Objects that send only monomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I just re-learned that fields can have only 1-to-1 homomorphisms from them. Is this a common trait in other categories? Can we extend, for instance, many topological spaces to spaces that have only 1-to-1 homomorphisms from them? In general, is there a name for a kind of object that only has injective arrows from such objects?

Comment: The constant map is always continuous, so only $\emptyset$ and $\{*\}$ are spaces such that all the maps out of them are monomorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

This won't happen for topological spaces except for the empty space and the one-point space (see Najib's comment). There is no general name for objects which have this "mono property". Apart from fields, only one other example comes to my mind, namely that of simple modules (over some ring; more generally simple objects of an abelian category). If $f : E \to M$ is a non-trivial module homomorphism, where $E$ is simple, then $\ker(f)=0$, i.e. $f$ is a monomorphism of modules.

Comment: Simple modules also admit the zero morphism to other modules. And similarly for simple groups. Maybe in $\mathsf{Set}_*$-enriched categories we should make an exception for zero maps.

Comment: That's why I have written "non-trivial module homomorphism".

Comment: Here's an idea which actually turns out to be kind of boring: If we make an exception for zero morphisms, perhaps for non-pointed categories, we should also make an exception for constant morphisms. Either way, the exception is for _morphisms that factor through the terminal object_, or (if you don't want to assume a terminal object) _morphisms which equalize all arrows_. This is kind of boring in $\mathsf{Set}$ or $\mathsf{Top}$: an object has all maps out either constant or injective iff it has at most two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Any terminal object has this property, and more generally, any [subterminal object](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subterminal+object). For example, in the category of sheaves over a topological space (or a locale), the sheaves corresponding to the open sets themselves are subterminal.

In some categories, every morphism is a monomorphism, e.g. any poset, the category of fields, or the category of [elementary embeddings](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/elementary+embedding) between structures of the same signature. In such categories, every object has this property.